# What is LT_INIT(...) in Linux?

Tags: android, linux, linphone

I'm customizing *linphone* (open source voip dialer).

When I build linphone-android from source, some errors occurr.

Problematic path is "submodules/libilbc-rfc3951/Makefile".

Error is like this:

```
./configure: line 2521: syntax error near unexpected token `disable-static'
./configure: line 2521: `LT_INIT(disable-static)'
```

What is '**LT_INIT(disable-static)**'?

And... What should I do about this?

It looks very complicated to me.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/LT_005fINIT.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Aduait Pokhriya.

Comment: @YoungWooLee hi M facing same problem .Can you share what have you done to solve it . Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, trying to install Lollypop, and i'm having this issue. Also, this question is on the wrong community.

Answer (score 2):

As Aduait had mentioned, http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/LT_005fINIT.html will explain what is LT_INIT(...).

Regarding the LinPhone-Android build issue, You got to remove submodules/libilbc-rfc3951/ and try to run make or prepare_source.sh respectively. It will fetch the right code for compilation.

I personally faced the same issue and the above method fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to defeat this one by going to `submodules/libilbc-rfc3951/` and running these commands:

- `aclocal`
- `autoconf`
- `automake --add-missing`